# HTTP call working with python but not with Android okhhtp

Tags: python, android, http, okhttp

I am facing a strange issue with Android.

I want to do a http call to https://api.moffi.io/api/orders/add.

I am using retrofit and defined this method:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("orders/add")
fun order(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Body order: Order): Call<JsonNode>
```

When calling it with an auth token, I get:

Error: USER_MUST_BE_CONNECTED.

Now when I do the same thing with python:

```
order = query(method="POST", url="/orders/add", data=body_order, auth_token=auth_token)

def query(  # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
    method: str,
    url: str,
    auth_token: str,
    params: Dict[str, str] = None,
    headers: Dict[str, str] = None,
    data: Dict[str, Any] = None,
) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    """
    Query Moffi API

    :param method: Used method (GET, POST, OPTIONS…)
    :param url: Moffi endpoint URL
    :param auth_token: Authentication token
    :param headers: custom headers
    :param data: body data
    :return: Json response
    :raise: RequestException
    """

    if not url.startswith(MOFFI_API):
        if not url.startswith("/"):
            url = f"/{url}"
        url = f"{MOFFI_API}{url}"

    if params:
        url = f"{url}?{urlencode(params)}"

    ciheaders = CaseInsensitiveDict()
    if headers is not None:
        for key, value in headers.items():
            ciheaders[key] = value

    ciheaders["Accept"] = "application/json"
    ciheaders["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {auth_token}"

    if method.lower() not in requests.__dict__:
        raise RecursionError(f"Unknown method {method}")
    method = requests.__dict__[method.lower()]

    try:
        result = method(url=url, headers=ciheaders, json=data)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as ex:
        raise RequestException from ex

    if result.status_code > 399:
        raise RequestException(f"Request error {result.status_code} {result.text}")

    return result.json()
```

It is working fine.

I am guessing there is a diffrence but I do not undestand what it is.

For more details, here is the Android code: https://github.com/moutyque/MoffiSimple

And the python: https://github.com/tduboys/moffi

Thx for any help

Comment: This is not a [mre].  It's missing several classes and any code to actually _call_ the API.

Comment: Instead of posting code, error messages, data, or other text as images or links, please [edit] your post to copy/paste or type the actual text directly into the post (for code, use a [code block](/editing-help#code)). [Text in images cannot be copied to reproduce the issue, and error messages in images cannot be searched](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Links may become invalid if the linked site changes. If your code is too long to fit in the post, we have tips on [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thx for your comment I will work on providing a minimal example.